# UIPageControl at Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

i've added an `UIPageController` in my application. I populate it from rest services and then when click one of page, it will goes directly to latest one. I'm missing something but what i cant solve. How can i make for get selected one instead of latest.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.FikirClick))
for item in self.ArrayList {
    say = say + 1
    self.frameFikirImage.origin.x = self.FikirscrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(say) + 10
    self.frameFikirImage.origin.y = 55
    self.imgFikirImage = UIImageView(frame: self.frameFikirImage)
    self.FikirscrollView.tag = item.id as! Int
    tapGesture.view?.tag = item.id as! Int

    self.imgFikirImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:  item.picture!))
    self.imgFikirImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    self.FikirscrollView.addSubview(self.imgFikirImage)
    self.frameFikirText.origin.x = self.FikirscrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(say) + 25
    self.frameFikirText.origin.y = 190
    self.lblFikir = UILabel(frame: self.frameFikirText)
    self.lblFikir.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.lblFikir.text = item.adi
    self.lblFikir.font = self.lblFikir.font.withSize(20)
    self.FikirscrollView.addSubview(self.lblFikir)


    self.frameFikirButton.origin.x = self.FikirscrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(say) + 20
    self.frameFikirButton.origin.y = 140


    self.FikirscrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
self.FikirscrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.FikirscrollView.frame.size.width * pageControlFikir,height: self.FikirscrollView.frame.size.height)

@objc func FikirClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var tag = sender.view!.tag
    print(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gesture need to be inside the for loop

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.FikirClick))
```

As it's for 1 view at a time so it's added to the last 1 when you click `var tag = sender.view!.tag`  with `tapGesture.view?.tag = item.id as! Int` update to last tag of the loop

Also make sure

```
self.imgFikirImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

and enable userinteration for the imageview